# PHP XML add elements

Tags: php, xml, addition

i tryed to do it with different codes but always with failure.

Here's my XML:

```
<movies>
  <movie>
    <title>Pav1</title>
    <plot>tekstas1</plot>
    </movie>
  <movie>
    <title>Pav2</title>
    <plot>tekstas2</plot>
  </movie>
</movies>
```

Here's the code i'm using:

```
<?php
  $xml = simplexml_load_file ( 'movies.xml' );
  $movies = $xml->addChild("movie");
  $movies->addChild("title", "title1");
  $movies->addChild("plot", "plot1");

  $xml->saveXML();
?>
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens after lounch.
Thanks, for any advice.

Comment: Did you forget to add an `echo` before `$xml->saveXML();`?

Comment: What exactly is the failure? As Wrikken said, you have to output/display the XML you've generated ... are you getting an actual error message?

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.org/R5PRcphF) when adding the `echo`...

Comment: idk if saveXML actually saves to file, try http://us2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php

Comment: @techjunkie.css: DOMDocument =/= SimpleXMLElement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not include the original filename in the last statement. This should fix it:

```
$xml->saveXML( 'movies.xml' );
```